scipy sosfilt array shape
I'm trying to plot a filter response in two ways, plot against time and the second plot against frequency. My aim is to plot cascaded filters, filter1 & filter2 for now.
The plot against frequency is where I'm stuck.
sosfreqz is expecting the sos array to have a (n_sections, 6) shape.
Could some kind person help?, I'm unsure how to fix this, haven't found a solution online yet.
I had it working in a (b, a) format but sos is apparently numerically more accurate.
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter, freqs, sosfilt, sosfiltfilt, convolve, sosfreqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def butter_lowpass_filter(signal, freq_cutoff, sampling_freq, filter_order):
    sos = butter(filter_order, freq_cutoff, fs=sampling_freq , btype='low', analog=False, output='sos')
    return sosfilt(sos, signal )

#***********************************************************************
#*   Inputs - values rads/s converted to Hz at plot
#***********************************************************************
frequency = 10                            # Frequency, Hz
amplitude = 1                               # Amplitude
theta = 0
duration = 1                                # Duration of signal, seconds
sample_rate = 44100                         # Samples per second
no_of_samples = int(duration * sample_rate) # total number of samples

#***********************************************************************
#*   generate X-axis (time)
t = np.linspace(0, duration, no_of_samples, endpoint=False)

#***********************************************************************
#* generate white noise - Y-axis
noise = np.random.normal(0, 1, no_of_samples)
noise = amplitude * (noise / np.max(np.abs(noise)))  # Normalize the white noise
#noise = (noise * 2**15).astype(np.int16)           # Convert the white noise to a 16-bit format

#***********************************************************************
#*   generate sin wave - Y-axis
sinewave = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * t + theta) + np.sin(2*np.pi*20*t)    # rad/s to Hz

signal = sinewave       # use this to change between noise & sinewave

#***********************************************************************
#*   Subplot 1 - Freq vs Time plot, Plot the original signal.
plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t, signal, label='input signal')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

#***********************************************************************
#*   Filter - stage 1
order = 2       # filter order number (20dB per decade)
cutoff = 27.5   # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz

y1 = butter_lowpass_filter(signal, cutoff, sample_rate, order)

#***********************************************************************
#*   Filter - stage 2
order = 2       # filter order number (20dB per decade)
cutoff = 121   # desired cutoff frequency of the filter, Hz

y2 = butter_lowpass_filter(signal, cutoff, sample_rate, order)

#***********************************************************************
#*   combine filters
y = convolve(y1, y2, mode='same')   # combine arrays, but maintain original size 'same'

#***********************************************************************
#*   Subplot 2 - Freq vs Time plot, Plot filtered signal.
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t, y, label='filtered_signal')
plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
plt.grid()
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

y = y1          # use this to change between y, y1, y2 

print(len(y), type(y), np.shape(y), y)

w, h = sosfreqz(y, worN=44100)
plt.figure(2)
#plt.subplot(2,1,3)
#plt.semilogx(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))              # Radians
plt.semilogx(w, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)) / (2* np.pi))  # Hz
plt.title('Butterworth filter frequency response')
plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
#plt.xlabel('Frequency [radians / second]')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
plt.margins(0, 0.1)
plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
plt.axvline(cutoff, color='green') # cutoff frequency

plt.show()


You can use sosfiltfilt() and combine the second order sections to sosfreqz and plot the frequency response:
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import butter, sosfiltfilt, sosfreqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def butter_lowpass_filter(signal, cutoff_freq, sampling_freq, filter_order):
    sos = butter(filter_order, cutoff_freq, fs=sampling_freq, btype='low', analog=False, output='sos')
    return sosfiltfilt(sos, signal)


def _gen_signal(amp, freq, duration, rate):
    t = np.linspace(0, duration, int(duration * rate), endpoint=False)
    signal = amp * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * t) + np.sin(2 * np.pi * 20 * t)
    return t, signal


def _plot_time(t, signal, filtered_signal):
    plt.figure(1)
    plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
    plt.plot(t, signal, label='input signal')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')

    plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
    plt.plot(t, filtered_signal, label='filtered_signal')
    plt.xlabel('Time [sec]')
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')


def _plot_frequency(sos, sample_rate):
    w, h = sosfreqz(sos, worN=sample_rate)
    freqs_hz = w * sample_rate / (2 * np.pi)
    plt.figure(2)
    plt.semilogx(freqs_hz, 20 * np.log10(abs(h)))
    plt.title('Butterworth filter frequency response')
    plt.xlabel('Frequency [Hz]')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude [dB]')
    plt.margins(0, 0.1)
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both')
    plt.show()


def run(*args):
    amplitude, frequency, theta, duration, sample_rate = args
    t, signal = _gen_signal(amplitude, frequency, duration, sample_rate)

    order, cutoff1 = 2, 27.5
    sos1 = butter(order, cutoff1, fs=sample_rate, btype='low', analog=False, output='sos')
    y1 = butter_lowpass_filter(signal, cutoff1, sample_rate, order)

    order, cutoff2 = 2, 121
    sos2 = butter(order, cutoff2, fs=sample_rate, btype='low', analog=False, output='sos')
    y2 = butter_lowpass_filter(signal, cutoff2, sample_rate, order)

    stack = np.vstack((sos1, sos2))
    sosff = sosfiltfilt(stack, signal)

    _plot_time(t, signal, sosff)
    _plot_frequency(stack, sample_rate)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    amp, freq = 1, 10
    theta, duration, sample_rate = 0, 1, 44100
    run(amp, freq, theta, duration, sample_rate)


Prints


Note

scipy.signal.sosfiltfilt

sos: "Array of second-order filter coefficients, must have shape (n_sections, 6). Each row corresponds to a second-order section, with the first three columns providing the numerator coefficients and the last three providing the denominator coefficients."

The sosfreqz() returns the normalized frequency values that need to be converted to Hz based on the sampling frequency.



Very cool, thankyou.
One question though the X-axis on the bode plot doesn't match the chosen frequencies.

27.5Hz & 121Hz, These two frequencies seems to be a factor of a 1000 to the left.

Perfect thankyou so much. :)
